# Inject .sql files in order using a docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm running an MySQL server docker container using a `docker-compose` YAML file.
Here is how the file looks like:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-dump/samples:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

In the `db` service, the volumne is set to `./mysql-dump/samples:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` this takes `.sql` files from `./mysql-dump/sample` to inject them to the database.

In my case I have two files `file2.sql` for the sql schema of the database, and `file1.sql` for the data.
Since the file appear to be injected in order, I get a `NO SUCH TABLE ERROR`, surely because the schema is injected last (because it's name is `file2.sql`)

Is there a way to reverse the order of the injection beside changing the names of the files?

Comment: Those two files should really be the same file, why are they separate?

Comment: Also alternative to having that directory would be to have your entrypoint set to run whatever sql files you need after starting the mysql service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go through the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) of mysql Dockerhub it clearly mentioned that it will dump file in alphabetical order.

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. **Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order.** You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL
>   dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
>   data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
>   by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

You need to replace file name, suppose `db.sql` and `table.sql` so it will first dump `db.sql` then `table.sql`

**Updated:**

To reverse the order of MySQL dump, you have to modify the docker file and entry point.

```
 FROM mysql:8
#From mysql
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3306 33060
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

**ENTRYPOINT:**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
set -eo pipefail
shopt -s nullglob

# if command starts with an option, prepend mysqld
if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
    set -- mysqld "$@"
fi

# skip setup if they want an option that stops mysqld
wantHelp=
for arg; do
    case "$arg" in
        -'?'|--help|--print-defaults|-V|--version)
            wantHelp=1
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

# usage: file_env VAR [DEFAULT]
#    ie: file_env 'XYZ_DB_PASSWORD' 'example'
# (will allow for "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD_FILE" to fill in the value of
#  "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD" from a file, especially for Docker's secrets feature)
file_env() {
    local var="$1"
    local fileVar="${var}_FILE"
    local def="${2:-}"
    if [ "${!var:-}" ] && [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
        echo >&2 "error: both $var and $fileVar are set (but are exclusive)"
        exit 1
    fi
    local val="$def"
    if [ "${!var:-}" ]; then
        val="${!var}"
    elif [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
        val="$(< "${!fileVar}")"
    fi
    export "$var"="$val"
    unset "$fileVar"
}

# usage: process_init_file FILENAME MYSQLCOMMAND...
#    ie: process_init_file foo.sh mysql -uroot
# (process a single initializer file, based on its extension. we define this
# function here, so that initializer scripts (*.sh) can use the same logic,
ls -r
process_init_file() {
    local f="$1"; shift
    local mysql=( "$@" )

    case "$f" in
        *.sh)     echo "$0: running $f"; . "$f" ;;
        *.sql)    echo "$0: running $f"; "${mysql[@]}" < "$f"; echo ;;
        *.sql.gz) echo "$0: running $f"; gunzip -c "$f" | "${mysql[@]}"; echo ;;
        *)        echo "$0: ignoring $f" ;;
    esac
    echo
}

_check_config() {
    toRun=( "$@" --verbose --help )
    if ! errors="$("${toRun[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/null)"; then
        cat >&2 <<-EOM

            ERROR: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
            command was: "${toRun[*]}"

            $errors
        EOM
        exit 1
    fi
}

# Fetch value from server config
# We use mysqld --verbose --help instead of my_print_defaults because the
# latter only show values present in config files, and not server defaults
_get_config() {
    local conf="$1"; shift
    "$@" --verbose --help --log-bin-index="$(mktemp -u)" 2>/dev/null \
        | awk '$1 == "'"$conf"'" && /^[^ \t]/ { sub(/^[^ \t]+[ \t]+/, ""); print; exit }'
    # match "datadir      /some/path with/spaces in/it here" but not "--xyz=abc\n     datadir (xyz)"
}

# allow the container to be started with `--user`
if [ "$1" = 'mysqld' -a -z "$wantHelp" -a "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
    _check_config "$@"
    DATADIR="$(_get_config 'datadir' "$@")"
    mkdir -p "$DATADIR"
    chown -R mysql:mysql "$DATADIR"
    exec gosu mysql "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
fi

if [ "$1" = 'mysqld' -a -z "$wantHelp" ]; then
    # still need to check config, container may have started with --user
    _check_config "$@"
    # Get config
    DATADIR="$(_get_config 'datadir' "$@")"

    if [ ! -d "$DATADIR/mysql" ]; then
        file_env 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'
        if [ -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -a -z "$MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD" -a -z "$MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
            echo >&2 'error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified '
            echo >&2 '  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD'
            exit 1
        fi

        mkdir -p "$DATADIR"

        echo 'Initializing database'
        "$@" --initialize-insecure
        echo 'Database initialized'

        if command -v mysql_ssl_rsa_setup > /dev/null && [ ! -e "$DATADIR/server-key.pem" ]; then
            # https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/23032807537d8dd8ee4ec1c4d40f0633cd4e12f9/packaging/deb-in/extra/mysql-systemd-start#L81-L84
            echo 'Initializing certificates'
            mysql_ssl_rsa_setup --datadir="$DATADIR"
            echo 'Certificates initialized'
        fi

        SOCKET="$(_get_config 'socket' "$@")"
        "$@" --skip-networking --socket="${SOCKET}" &
        pid="$!"

        mysql=( mysql --protocol=socket -uroot -hlocalhost --socket="${SOCKET}" )

        for i in {30..0}; do
            if echo 'SELECT 1' | "${mysql[@]}" &> /dev/null; then
                break
            fi
            echo 'MySQL init process in progress...'
            sleep 1
        done
        if [ "$i" = 0 ]; then
            echo >&2 'MySQL init process failed.'
            exit 1
        fi

        if [ -z "$MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO" ]; then
            # sed is for https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20545
            mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | sed 's/Local time zone must be set--see zic manual page/FCTY/' | "${mysql[@]}" mysql
        fi

        if [ ! -z "$MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
            export MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="$(pwgen -1 32)"
            echo "GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
        fi

        rootCreate=
        # default root to listen for connections from anywhere
        file_env 'MYSQL_ROOT_HOST' '%'
        if [ ! -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_HOST" -a "$MYSQL_ROOT_HOST" != 'localhost' ]; then
            # no, we don't care if read finds a terminating character in this heredoc
            # https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265149/why-is-set-o-errexit-breaking-this-read-heredoc-expression/265151#265151
            read -r -d '' rootCreate <<-EOSQL || true
                CREATE USER 'root'@'${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST}' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}' ;
                GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST}' WITH GRANT OPTION ;
            EOSQL
        fi

        "${mysql[@]}" <<-EOSQL
            -- What's done in this file shouldn't be replicated
            --  or products like mysql-fabric won't work
            SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN=0;

            ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}' ;
            GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION ;
            ${rootCreate}
            DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test ;
            FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;
        EOSQL

        if [ ! -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
            mysql+=( -p"${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" )
        fi

        file_env 'MYSQL_DATABASE'
        if [ "$MYSQL_DATABASE" ]; then
            echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$MYSQL_DATABASE\` ;" | "${mysql[@]}"
            mysql+=( "$MYSQL_DATABASE" )
        fi

        file_env 'MYSQL_USER'
        file_env 'MYSQL_PASSWORD'
        if [ "$MYSQL_USER" -a "$MYSQL_PASSWORD" ]; then
            echo "CREATE USER '$MYSQL_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_PASSWORD' ;" | "${mysql[@]}"

            if [ "$MYSQL_DATABASE" ]; then
                echo "GRANT ALL ON \`$MYSQL_DATABASE\`.* TO '$MYSQL_USER'@'%' ;" | "${mysql[@]}"
            fi

            echo 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;' | "${mysql[@]}"
        fi

        echo 
        ls -r /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ > /dev/null
        for f in $(ls -r /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*); do
            process_init_file "$f" "${mysql[@]}"
        done

        if [ ! -z "$MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD" ]; then
            "${mysql[@]}" <<-EOSQL
                ALTER USER 'root'@'%' PASSWORD EXPIRE;
            EOSQL
        fi
        if ! kill -s TERM "$pid" || ! wait "$pid"; then
            echo >&2 'MySQL init process failed.'
            exit 1
        fi

        echo
        echo 'MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.'
        echo
    fi
fi

exec "$@"
```

If you run the container, You will see the file is in processing **reverse** order

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I went through already, my question was if there is a way other than renaming the files.

Comment: If you are using official image then you've to rename, other way is to modify entry points